# Django media uploads to Amazon S3 and restricting access to certain users

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I am creating a flutter application with Djano backend where users can create/join groups and upload files (pictures, videos etc) to the group.
I set up AWS S3 storage to handle media file uploads.
However, now I'm at a point where I want only members of a group in the app to be able to see those files/pictures and restrict access to those files/pictures where you are not a member of the group.
right now My bucket settings is set to public and anyone that has a link to the URL can access/view that file in the browser.

How would I implement if someone grabs a hold of that URL , they shouldn't be able to access the file by going to the link.

essentially, some content like profile pictures can be public and anyone can access that but no one can just go to their browser and type in a URL for a certain file link and access it.

How would I go about doing this? Are there any good tutorials that you can link me or documentation that discusses this?

Comment: Hi, this is probably what you are looking for https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/